# How to pass each value of array to specific variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to transfer the value of my array into my variables.
My array contain 2 value, [0]Firstname [1]Lastname.
i want to store it to

```
$fname = array[0] //firstname
$lname = array[1] //lastname
```

here's my code:

```
<?php
$str  = "Firstname.Lastname@email.com";
$str = str_replace('@email.com', '', $str);
print_r ((explode(".",$str)), true);
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You get the first name and last name from the email address. What do you want to do next? Assign the values from array into scalar variables? You already do it at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this is what you seek:

```
list( $fname, $lname ) = explode( '.', $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
list($name) = explode('@', $str);
list($fname, $lname) = explode('.', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
$str = "Firstname.Lastname@email.com";

preg_match('~(?P<fname>.+?)\.(?P<lname>.+?)@(?P<host>.+)$~', $str, $matches);
extract($matches);

var_dump($fname);
var_dump($lname);
var_dump($host);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str  = "Firstname.Lastname@email.com";
$str = str_replace('@email.com', '', $str);
$str = explode(".",$str);

$fname = $str[0] //firstname
$lname = $str[1] //lastname
```